# apply function on array third dimension

Tags: r

I have a large array, this is a replicable example:

```
cube <- array(c(1:10,5:15,-5:+5,1:18), c(4, 4, 3)) 
cube
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9    7
[2,]    2    6   10    8
[3,]    3    7    5    9
[4,]    4    8    6   10

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   11   15   -2    2
[2,]   12   -5   -1    3
[3,]   13   -4    0    4
[4,]   14   -3    1    5

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

I would like to apply this function for each "floor" of my array (3rd dimension):

```
m1 <- cube[,,1]
m2 <- cube[,,2]
m3 <- cube[,,3]
library(data.table)
m1[] <- frank(-m1, ties.method = "dense")
m2[] <- frank(-m2, ties.method = "dense")
m3[] <- frank(-m3, ties.method = "dense")
```

Then, since the replicable example is very small. I can do the final work of combining matrixes easily by:

```
z <- array( c( m1 , m2, m3 ) , dim = c( 4 , 4 , 3 ) )
z
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10    6    2    4
[2,]    9    5    1    3
[3,]    8    4    6    2
[4,]    7    3    5    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    1   13    9
[2,]    4   16   12    8
[3,]    3   15   11    7
[4,]    2   14   10    6

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   16   12    8    4
[2,]   15   11    7    3
[3,]   14   10    6    2
[4,]   13    9    5    1
```

I need a fast way to do this in my large array. Any help?Thanks.

Comment: I would `melt` your array into a data.table and work with that. But you can use `apply` too.

Comment: The apply way: `array(apply(-cube, 3, frank, ties.method="dense"), dim(cube))` but I wouldn't expect it to be fast. I think Roland's idea is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

The function `apply` is made for that. the second argument `MARGIN` specifies the dimension along which you apply the function.

```
res <- apply(-cube, 3, frank, ties.method = "dense")
## reshape:
array(res, dim=dim(cube))
```