# How to iterate over each dimension of a multi-dimensional array, or turn an array into a list of matrices: R

Tags: r, arrays

I have this example array in R:

```
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
vec2 <- c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)

exampleArray <- array(c(vec1, vec2), dim = c(2, 3, 3))
```

It produces the following three matrices in the form of an array:

```
> exampleArray
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   15   17
[2,]   14   16   18
```

I have done the computations to the array I want to do, and now I want to write a function that iterates over each matrix, or undoes the array into a list of matrices. I was thinking of using a for loop similar in structure to iterating over the rows or columns of a matrix, but I couldn't find a way to produce a list of values through the third dimension of an array. I could make this work if I could turn this array into a list of matrices, so please provide that as an answer too.

Do note that my actual data is huge, I have a folder of arrays, all different in the number of matrices they contain (IE the third dimension length), though all matrices are the same dimensions (IE lengths of dimensions 1 and 2 are equal across all arrays), so I would like the solution to be dynamic in that I don't need to manually type in exampleArray[,,1], etc, etc.

This is not my first time asking basic and stupid questions here, no need to nice, humiliation is acceptable. Though an answer is appreciated.

Comment: `apply(exampleArray, 3, FUN)` ? I think I have a previous answer which discusses this - let me see if I can find it again.

Comment: Useful info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197330/using-apply-on-a-multidimensional-array-in-r and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275279/apply-function-on-array-third-dimension

Comment: @thelatemail That works! I can access each matrix as well as turn it into a list of matrices depending on how I write the function. Many thanks!

Comment: to transform it to a list of matrices, do: `asplit(your_array, 3)`